# How to find a number of ways in network if rate is not constant?

Tags: combinatorics, graph-theory

Assume I have a simple graph, and a number of ways I can go down can be found as $2^n$, where base is a constant number of rate.[image]
And my question is following: **How can I find a number of ways in such graph, but if rate is not a constant.** Example:

[image]

Comment: It's just the products of the rates at each level. In your example, this works out to $2\times 3\times 2$.

Comment: In a tree, there's a unique path from the root to a leaf, so even if the number of branches at each node in a level isn't constant across the level, the number of paths equals the number of leaves.

Comment: @saulspatz Interesting, but I'm not sure this helps.  In his query diagrams, you can simply count the leaves, but in the general problem, I would guess (perhaps wrongly) that counting or enumerating the individual leaves is not viable.   If I'm right, it seems that the fallback is the comment of Mike Earnest.